# Are the different C++ standards comparable to the different Java versions?

Tags: java, c++, iso

Suppose there is a simple application which uses Java 8 features. This means:

1. The developer must have had JDK 1.8 to develop it.
2. The end user must have at least JRE 1.8.

In C++, there are different standards. On [C++ shell](http://cpp.sh/) it lists three: C++98, C++11, C++14. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization) lists more.

My question is: are these like Java versions?

Comment: `The end user must have at least JRE 1.8.` ?? No need.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Please elaborate! It's a simple program, so no embedding or fancy tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. To use C++11/14 features you need a compiler that supports these features. But note that C++ compilers don't have the same all-or-nothing approach to versions as Java compilers, i.e. you may have a compiler that supports *some* C++11 and C++14 features, but not all of them.

There isn't anything like the JRE for C++. C++ is compiled to native executables. You may need to distribute some libraries that you use, and if you use a newer compiler, the compiler's libraries that you have to distribute may be different too. But it really isn't different from any other library.